# Where are really the log files to debug when a Windows 10 update fails?

Tags: windows-10, installation, logging, windows-10-upgrade

I am struggling with Win 10 update:

```
Feature update to Windows 10, version 1809 x64 2020-03B - Error 0x80070490
```

Google is swamped with useless articles about random peoples' experiences, but no actual or systematic solutions, and I've already done the usual solutions [`DSIM`, `Sfc`]:

- According to my research, `0x80070490` relates to a driver problem, but in Device Manager everything is okay and all devices work as expected (Windows must somewhere place more information than this stupid code)
- Supposedly there should be log files within `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback`, but `Rollback` does not exist; similarly, there are no (current) files in `C:\Windows\Panther\`, or useful info in the Event log

Where does the update actually put the log files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, where does the update actually put the log files?

If an update fails to install, the reason for the failure will be contained within `%systemroot%\Logs\CBS`, and if Windows Update itself has an error, it will be logged within `Event Tracing for Windows` (.etl) files; a human-readable text file can be generated via PowerShell command: `Get-WindowsUpdateLog`

Source: [Windows Update log files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-logs)

> Supposedly there should be log files in `c:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback` but `Rollback` does not even exist. Similarly, no (current) files in `c:\Windows\Panther`. No useful info in the Event log.

Based on my experience this log only applies to problems upgrading to another version of Windows.