# Why is my VM still on v1809 of Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a Windows 10 Pro image running under Parallels. It's been working since W7, updating through W8->W10 and several W10 updates. It did a fairly big update just last week but investigating, I see it is still on 1809, and Windows Update warns me "You're currently using a version of Windows that's nearing the end of service".

This machine is running all the time so why is it not updating?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound can you rephase that more specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1536806/where-are-really-the-log-files-to-debug-when-a-windows-10-update-fails/1536813#1536813

Comment: @Ramhound I aded update history. I haven't seen any errors

Comment: Wait a week and then restart the VM before you next try to update.  If you happy with the current install, run Disk Cleanup, Clean up System Files, to remove Windows.ol. See what happens in 7 days.

Comment: I am going to guess you have configured the VM to postpone feature and cumulative updates for a period of time.  Is that the case?  You can determine if that is the case by looking within Windows Update and looking at the Advanced Options.  You just recently installed Windows 10 version 1809 which means the VM was running either `Windows 10 version 1709` or `Windows 10 version 1803` prior to April 4th 2020.

Comment: @Ramhound I was wondering that. See 3rd image... I have deferment allowed, _but_ surely I would still see the new version available and be bugged to install it?

Comment: @Mr.Boy - Why would you expect that to happen?  You asked Windows specifically to defer the installation of feature updates for 365 days.  `Windows 10 version 1909` and `Windows 10 version 1903` is only installed if you seek to install it.

Comment: @Ramhound the setting says "_can_ be deferred" not "_will_ be deferred"...

Comment: @Mr.Boy - Yes;  You can defer the feature upgrade for 365 days;  You have deferred the upgrade to 1809 for 365 days.  You are deferring the upgrade to 1909 for 365 days.  Why are you resisting to accept my explanation as fact?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible since it only updated to 1809 a few days back, it hasn't scheduled a newer update yet?

You have configured your system to check for feature updates every 365 days.

> This machine is running all the time so why is it not updating?

**You have configured it to postpone feature updates for 365 days and to postpone quality updates for 30 days.**

Based on your settings prior to April 4th, 2020, you were running `Windows 10 version 1709`, you must have installed `Windows 10 version 1709` around April 4th, 2019.  `KB4537759` was released approximately 30 days ago, for `Windows 10 version 1809`, on February 10th 2020. Windows is doing exactly what you have configured it to do.

> I would still see the new version available and be bugged to install it?

**You asked Windows specifically to defer the installation of feature updates for 365 days.**  `Windows 10 version 1909` and `Windows 10 version 1903` is only installed if you seek to install it.

> [image]

Windows Update received some very specific upgrades with `Windows 10 version 1903` and `Windows 10 version 1909` with regards to how feature updates are installed.  So some of the expected behavior does actually happen, however, if you postpone feature upgrades the feature update is still not listed.

**You will not be forced to upgrade to `Windows 10 version 1909` until Windows 10 version 1809 reaches end of service**

Comment: So, I would like to be able to defer updates but in this instance I would like to update now. Is this possible through Windows Update - to find that update and manually select it?

Comment: @Mr.Boy - Just disable the deferment of feature updates for 365 days. Your question made no mention of wanting to upgrade to 1909.