# Windows ver.2004 Update Failure

Tags: windows-10-v2004

Windows Update Standalone Installer's response is - the update is not applicable to your computer.
I have a CBS.log file related to this case but I cannot submit it for your further analysis because the size of it is about 91.3 KB and the limit of **SUPERUSER's body** size is 30,000 characters ( 29.3 KB ).
Any idea how to proceed with that ?

```
**From wmicos.txt**
```

1. BuildNumber=19041
2. Caption=Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
3. CreationClassName=Win32_OperatingSystem
4. Locale=0409
5. OSType=18
6. OperatingSystemSKU=48
7. ProductType=1
8. RegisteredUser=RW
9. Version=10.0.19041
10. WindowsDirectory=C:\WINDOWS
11. ServicePackMajorVersion=0
12. Manufacturer=Microsoft Corporation
13. CSName=DELL
14. OSArchitecture=32-bit
15. PAEEnabled=True
16. MaxProcessMemorySize=2097024
17. NumberOfProcesses=98
18. FreeVirtualMemory=2437836
19. FreePhysicalMemory=1122352
20. FreeSpacePagingFiles=1836852

### I have been trying to update OS Build from 10.0.19041.329 to 10.0.19041.388 ( in this attached above example ) and etc. using next update patches between June and November, 2020. All my attempts fail with the same response - the update is not applicable to your computer.
Running SFC and DISM did not reveal any system files corruption. Also, I tried to do the upgrade using
Windows ISO file disabling 3rd party antivirus app (Norton 360 ). The installation failed as well.
Only I avoided off a clean installation of Windows which requires to re-install all my apps on this machine.
How to fix this culprit ?

---

Reviewing the CBS.log ( some of conclusions) :

1. **Failed to find a matching version for servicing stack.**
2. **Failed to find servicing stack directory in online store**
   **[Hresult=0x80070490-Error_Not_Found ]**
3. **Appl:Evaluating package applicability for Package_for_RollupFix_~.....~~19041.388.1.7, applicable state:Absent.**

I used following commands: **sfc /scannow** - result clean,
**dism /online /cleanup-image /ScanHealth** and **dism /online /cleanup-imag**e **/RestoreHealth** - result clean.
Regarding @Ramhound's suspicion that **WinSxS** folder files might be corrupted with my mishap to update, I used another command as well as
**dism /online /cleanup-image /RestoreHealth /Source:I:\sources\install.wim, where
I: drive is where I mounted my ISO.**

### Link where you will find **CBS1.LOG** file
**https://we.tl/t-QJm9vMuBZR**

Starting September,2020 MS bundles LCU and SSU together. I downloaded KB4577266 patch and tried to install it, the process failed. Please see the uploaded **CBS.log**
**https://we.tl/t-syDzeLjayj**

### Also, before LCU and CCU install I tried to run **sfc /scannow in Windows safe** **mode.** No corruptions were detected.

**https://we.tl/t-Y1NLAvdTrM**
I uploaded a copy of C:\windows\system32\config\components in **components.txt** file which is very gibberish to view those hives. I guess, they are as well as somewhere in registry under HKLM.

In addition, I reviewed CBS.log file:

- **CBS failed to find a matching version for servicing stack
  C:\windows\winSxS\X86_MS_Windows-serrvicing stack........10.0.19041.329.......** **[Hresult=0x80070490 ]**

I looked at the folder and found this file ( so it exists ! ), date modified 6/19/2020 when my Windows 10 ver.1909 got upgraded to ver.2004 (19041.329 ).

- **Loaded servicing stack v10.0.19041.329 with core ..........\cbscore.dll**

  I found that file with date modified 6/3/2020.
- **Evaluating package applicability for package KB4577266, applicable state:Absent
  No parent found, go absent.**
  My "nonprofessional" conclusion - if the SSU from 6/3/20 is corrupted, based on
  the marked error code, however, it was marked clearly as error not found why the system did not accept the new SSU (KB4577266 )
  2020-09 as a replacement for the corrupted ?

---

### **https://we.tl/t-chJ9nqKGH3** **ComponentBasedServicing** and **Export(ServicingStackVersions)**
I am puzzled, why under HKLM\ hive I do not see in my registry key Components  with other subkeys? Only when I create a new key "Components" and click "Load hive" I get that what is hidden in C:\windows\system32\config\components.
Also when I reboot the machine the created hive under HKLM\ disappears.

I downloaded FRST app and created Fixlist.txt. For @ Tekkie_Boy's attention:
Fixlist cannot be downloaded from the same site, I found there is a batch file on another site, the batch file should be pasted in a NotePad window and renamed as Fixlist.txt and later the FRST app renames it in FixLog.txt.
**https://we.tl/t-y62Vvqrdy0** So the FixLog file is created for your review.

---

**https://we.tl/t-fUHAegI7uJ**

FRST app after launching, it creates own folder FRST where are subfolders.
Among them is a folder LOG where FixLog.txt file is laying.

---

### After using the FRST app to scan and fix Components packages of Windows ver.2004
I got back "Windows Optional Features" and could install SSU patch KB4577266 without any issue.
**However, all sequential  cumulative updates fail to be installed with error code 0x800f0831.**

Yes, DISM ended in a failure with error code 0x800f081f-the source files could not be found.
I continued as well as with sfc /scannow and uploaded for you another CBS.LOG file.**https://we.tl/t-5V9ARniltQ**
Yesterday, I did an extra work - decided to see whether WINISO ( 19041.572 ) can be installed successfully upgrading my current OS. The process at end failed:
"The system registry contains invalid file paths. Installation cannot proceed.
The system image was applied without guaranteeing that driver-letter assignments
would match across computers.
Undoing changes made to your computer.
0xC1900101-0x30018 The installation failed in the First_Boot phase with an error during Sysprep-Specialize operation."
So it restored my machine to 19041.329 back.

Comment: With which error code fails the Updates?

Comment: What do the Windows Update log indicate.  Please note, the update log must be generated, using the appropriate command as the data is not otherwise contained in a rolling log.  You can use Setup Diag a Microsoft tool to determine the reason the upgrade from 2004 to 20H2 is failing

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1536806/where-are-really-the-log-files-to-debug-when-a-windows-10-update-fails/1536813#1536813) are instructions to dump the Windows Update log.  Please edit your question to include this vital information.  You should also explicitly indicate which updates your attempting to install.  Please do not submit a comment instead edit your question. We also need to know the last cumulative update you installed.  You should also provide us the output of the appropriate DISM and SFC commands.  Again, edit your question, instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound, I am not trying to upgrade from 2004 to 20H2 but update from 19041.329 up. Regarding your recommendation to use Setup Diag MS Tool, I was unsuccessful with it . As soon as I launch this tool, it creates a SetupDiagLog file with 0 bytes and I do not see any increase in that file size.

Comment: You said you tried using the Windows 10 ISO which I assumed was 20H2 since the 2004 ISO wouldn’t have been recently generated by Microsoft.  If that’s the case then Setup Diag wouldn’t have any logs to process.  I suspect severe corruption of your WinSxS folder is to blame for your inability to install patches which is the reason for the DISM and SFC commands

Comment: @Aventure Please copy the CBS folder to the desktop, zip it and then upload it on [wetransfer](https://wetransfer.com) and share the link here.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy, Thanks for your help with the link.

Comment: @Aventure Disable Norton 360 and then download the [Farbar Recovery Scan Tool](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/farbar-recovery-scan-tool) 32 bit Version and save it on your desktop. After that download this [Fixlist](https://we.tl/t-AtsZBKPHM5) and save it on your desktop too, Make **sure** the fixlist is in the same folder as the Farbar Tool. Start the Farbar Recovery Scan Tool with a right click on the file and select the option "**Run as administrator**". Then press the **Fix** button and wait until the process is finished. The tool generate a Fixlog.txt. Please upload it again.

Comment: @Tekkiie_Boy, I compared both FixLists. Now it makes a sense because the later FixList contains Windows ver.2004 registry hives related to the Components and FRST scans my machine and compares it with that list. I am wondering where is the difference between FRST and DISM/.../RestoreHealth ?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate very much  @ Tekkie_Boy who spend with me a lot of time.
I can report today after trying again to use Microsoft Media Creation Tool my Windows OS got finally successfully upgraded from 19041.329 to 19042.685 ( ver. 20H2 ).
Everything functions correctly. I hope it stays this way.
Regards,
@Aventure

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've written a summary of my work so that posterity will understand the analysis and repair. Stay safe!

Comment: @Tekky_Boy, I downloaded FRST instructions deciding to understand how great is that tool in fixing Windows problems. In our case you added scripts to fixlist based on

Comment: @Tekky_Boy, Why  cannot be used  scan log file of FRST to add necessary script(s) to fixlist.txt rather to use Windows CBS.LOG and Registry.LOG files ?

Comment: @Adventure The FRST is primarily a tool for repairing malware and/or virus-infected systems. It is therefore intended for experts who look at the log files after the scan and then create the necessary scripts. CBS.logs must also be evaluated and appropriate solutions worked out. And Windows Update repairs are not always possible or sufficient with a fixlist.

Comment: @Tekky_Boy, I am sorry to be persistent but the FRST manual provides a different prospective for this tool. While it scans providing the Whitelisting has checkmarks for various components it should come up in FRST.txt with some errors. I have another

Comment: machine HP Lenovo where I know about the problems but FRST comes with a clean bill.

Comment: @Tekky_Boy, I read if you want to see a full log in FRST after a scan, the relevant boxes on the Whitelist section should be checked. I disabled my antivirus app and installed FRST app on other machine. For some reason I do not get a full log (FRST.txt)  just a header about my PC without details about the checked items under Whitelisting section. What could be the reason ?

Comment: @Tekky_Boy, I found the reason for previously described problem with FRST app. When I used FRST app  version you advised me last week ( we call it older version ) it works fine but today when I launched it I got an automatic update which has a bug. I hope the creator of app will fix it.

Comment: @Adventure Thanks for your information.