# DLL reported as missing in WinSxS, but exists

Tags: windows-10, dll, winsxs

My laptop runs Windows 10, and when I try to lauch some installers, the following error appears:

> The code execution cannot proceed because

```
C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.488_none_11b1e5df2ffd8627\comctl32.dll
```

was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

The comctl32.dll file actually exists:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx>dir C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.488_none_11b1e5df2ffd8627\comctl32.dll
Volume in drive C is Windows  Volume Serial Number is DAB7-B2B1
Directory of C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.488_none_11b1e5df2ffd8627

2020-10-31  02:04         2 156 344 comctl32.dll
               1 File(s)      2 156 344 bytes
```

How is that possible?

I tried to run:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
SFC /SCANNOW
```

but I still get the error.  I had the same issue last year, and I reinstalled Windows 10.  I suspect an application to be the issue, but it's hard to find.  Understanding **why an existing file is reported as missing** might help.

Another thing.  Since installers often fail to run, the last Windows Update also fails.  So everyday, it runs, ask me to reboot, fails to install, rolls back, and attempts to reinstall again.  I cannot run some commands because of that (restart pending).  Link to the Windows Update log: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah7tuKnUcIldk7QWUdooJxAiuR7E4A?e=71zdpi

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "How is that possible?" - Data corruption;  This is likely an indication that your system drive will develop a problem.  You will have to provide more specific information than "it didn't help." if you want a detailed answer.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: [You need to provide us the Windows Update log.](https://superuser.com/questions/1536806/where-are-really-the-log-files-to-debug-when-a-windows-10-update-fails/1536813#1536813)

Answer (score 1):

Start with the initial Windows 10 Repair steps.

Open `cmd.exe` with Run as Administrator.

```
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  
dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth
SFC /SCANNOW
```

Restart and test the installers.

Note: If, for some reason, you need the source for your DISM command, try the steps in the article here:

[Dism Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/how-to-repair-the-source-for-dism-when/50f0d4de-b230-4585-a243-ab477422a043)

There are too many steps to reprint and this is just a fall back.  I prefer a Windows 10 Repair over trying to fix DISM Source.

If the above fails, you need to use the Windows 10 Repair Install.

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Be aware that the steps above do not fix a damaged Windows User Profile.  If the Windows User Profile is damaged, you need to replace it.

Comment: You are suggesting something the author already tried.  You might want to update your answer to use an valid source for the DISM commands.

Comment: I added the step for Start Component Cleanup to see if that would help. That is why I added the next step (I did read that). And then the step to repair Windows.  I hope that clarifies.

Comment: I did add some steps about DISM source but I have found DISM source most unsatisfying. I prefer a Windows 10 Repair Install which is now reliably kept up to date. Thank you for your assistance.