# Why did my DLL disappear?

Tags: windows, dll, shared-libraries, windows-libraries

I have two similar computers (same OS and similar software), both of which have run Minecraft for years. But when I started Minecraft today, I got this error: "The program can't start because MSVCP140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." The problem happened on both computers.

**I don't need help getting the DLL.** My question is: what made the DLL "disappear"? The program worked fine yesterday.

FYI: That file is actually present in several locations on my computer, including in `c:\windows\system32`.

I do **not** have Visual Studio installed. I am using Windows 7.

Update: fifteen days later, the problem happened again, on both computers.

Comment: Windows has specific locations it looks for a referenced file like MSVCP140.dll, if the file is not found in one of those locations, the very last location it looks for it is in the folder that contains the executable. Do you have Visual C++ 2015 installed?  Minecraft will either require the 32-bit or 64-bit version of it to be installed.  Please [edit] your question to include the necessary information to diagnose your system.

Comment: No, I don't have Visual C++ or Visual Studio installed. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: DLLs are handled "magically" via WinSXS so there might be a problem with the windows side-by-side repository. See, for example: https://superuser.com/questions/1616678/dll-reported-as-missing-in-winsxs-but-exists

Comment: @Yorik - `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` would not be managed by WinSxS.  `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` is only installed by the user.  If the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` installation was corrupt it would not be detected in a scan with DISM or SFC.

Comment: @DanR. - I didn't actually ask if you had Visual Studio installed.  I ask if you had the `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` installed.  Now if you don't have `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` installed, then it was uninstalled, and that would have only happened if you had uninstalled it.  `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` when it required for an application, like for instance Minecraft, typically is installed by the installer for the application that requires it.  So do you have `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable` installed?

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1163409/msvcp120-dll-and-msvcr120-dll-are-missing/1163505#1163505) is a relevant answer that might be applicable to this issue.

Comment: I don't know whether Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable was installed, because I am not the one who installed most of the software.