# How to update Windows 11

Tags: windows, updates, windows-11

I just installed Windows 11 on my ThinkPad X13 gen 2 (released in April 2021). After I installed the update, I get this error message every time I try it again:

> We couldn't install updates because there's a problem with the date and time information on your device. Make sure your date, time, and time zone settings are correct and we'll try again later.

The Windows update log shows some messages with *failed*. But I'm not sure which of the 1000 different error messages are relevant. The log is too big to show.

Time is correct, correct Time server. Synchronized seconds before a try.

Windows Update Log available at: http://gofile.me/6t5KG/4YhkMVrmh

Comment: Have you checked that the date, time and timezone are correct?

Comment: Make sure your computer is less than 4 years old, uses UEFI, has secure boot, and has TPMv2.  It may not be compliant and that may be why it won't update. My own production Windows 11 Pro machine (new) updates fine.

Comment: Updated Question.

Comment: I suggest trying to use the [Windows 11 Installation Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) instead of allowing Windows Update to install it.  Generate the WindowsUpdate.log using the appropriate [method](https://superuser.com/questions/1536806) and look for the following message: "A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file." You should [edit] your question to include this vital and require information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: windows 11 is installed. I only want update the existing installation

Comment: Please post online the log (OneDrive, Dropbox etc), as it's too large. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc added log infos