# Buggy Rebooting and Install Failure

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

my system (windows 10) wants to do a shutdown or reboot to install a windows update.  When I try the shut down, it will go through the normal steps, but then reboot itself with no input.  After it comes on, it continues to work on the update, until it hits 100%.  Then it gives the error "We couldn’t complete the updates. Undoing changes".  This also happens if I tell it to reboot and install updates.

I can do normal shutdown/reboot, but when I do the MSI logo screen comes up, glitches out, then comes up again.  The only other issue is that my USB ports appear to be off now when it is booting up, so I can't access BIOS.  Other than these issues, I'm not noticing problems while the machine is running.

I went through the hardware and verified that there are no loose or damaged cables.  My processor is still firmly seated, and does not appear to have issues.  Also, my antivirus (Symantec) is coming up clean.

Any suggestions on other things I could check, or potential issues?  Thanks everyone!

Edit: I forgot to mention the two problems that I originally had.  My power button is supposed to put the computer in sleep mode, but about a month ago all it would do is turn off the display.  Peripherals were still powered, fans would run constantly, and the screen would come on if I so much as moved the mouse.  It used to be that I had to hit the power button again to bring it up.  After that started happening, I noticed that attempting to use the regular shutdown would result in the computer rebooting itself.  This problem has stopped happening, but I'm not sure what caused it, or why it stopped.

Comment: Try for starters DISM and SFC   ........    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test and try updating again

Comment: Provide the [Windows Update log](https://superuser.com/questions/1536806/where-are-really-the-log-files-to-debug-when-a-windows-10-update-fails/1536813#1536813) as an [edit] to your question. We cannot help without that log.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not familiar with generating update logs. I opened powershell, and ran the copied syntax command from the update log link that someone provided as an answer. The output is a file which has 1421 lines of text. Is that what you wanted? How do I upload it for you to see?

Comment: Since the basic steps are having issues, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link.    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button and use the option to Keep Everything for starters.

Comment: @John Okay, I picked regular reboot, but it started the update process anyway.  Everything was running normally, it got to 100%, but then it kicked back to the MSI boot screen again, which blinked on and off a few times.  After that, it had a normal boot, except that some status LEDs on the motherboard came up amber and white, which I've not noticed before (but I don't usually check, so I don't know if that's abnormal).  Checking now to see if updates went through.

Comment: @John No luck unfortunately.  I told it to update and reboot, but it resulted in the error I was having before.  I'll attempt the repair install tomorrow.  Would it be advisable to create a backup before I try that?

Comment: I keep a daily backup of important files and documents as a matter of course. You should also back up important things. However, Repair Install has always been safe for me. Be sure however and have important backups.

Comment: @John Okay, thanks.  I don't really have anything important on here.

Comment: So just run the Repair, use Keep Everything and then see how it goes.

Comment: @DavidRobie - I linked you to instructions to generate the required logs