# Win8.1 updates failing for months

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I just noticed that nearly all of my Windows updates have been failing since 4/17/2022:

[image: failed Windows updates]

Just a few exceptions succeeded:

[image: successful Windows updates]

I tried following the suggestions at:
https://www.800error.com/KB2962409-windows-update-error-knowledge-kb-ms-security-fail

1. Stopping the Windows Update service and clearing
   `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore`

   (then restarting the service, of course) didn't help
2. When I tried running
   `C:\Windows\system32>sfc/scannow`

   I got this message:
   `Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
   Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.`
3. I looked at the Registry but found that
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`

   had neither WUServer nor WIStatusServer

When I tried to run Windows Update again, it just keeps checking endlessly.

Upgrading to Windows 10 (or 11) isn't at all an option now, so I would truly appreciate help getting the updates for 8.1 working.

What else could I do to get all those updates applied?

Comment: If you want our help you will have to provide the Windows Update log.  I would prefer not to have to sort through 2 months of logs, so perhaps clear the history and then attempt the installation of a patch to provide a minimal amount of data.  Your inability to run SFC or DISM suggests a repair install of Windows 8.1 might be the best way forward.  An ability to run SFC suggest sever system corruption (or simply the require service isn't running).

Comment: I assume you're talking about logs from this folder: 
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs ? If so, which / how many files should I upload?

Comment: I am not.  The logs in that directory have nothing to do with Windows Update.  You have to run a documented command to convert the Windows Update (ETL) logs into a text document. [However, I just realized the command, only supports Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1536806/where-are-really-the-log-files-to-debug-when-a-windows-10-update-fails/1536813#1536813).  All that means is that without detail information on what is failing exactly, I can't diagnose the issue, so my suggestion of performing a repair install seems like the best way forward.

Comment: I verified the Windows Modules Installer service was running and set to Manual startup. I tried stopping the service which failed; restarting it seemed to succeed. But when I reran the SFC check, I got the same message.  

Is the [Startup Repair tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems#method-1-startup-repair-tool) (optionally run upon system start) the same as doing a repair install?

Comment: No; Startup Repair Tool is not the same as doing a repair install.